# Spring JMS - autowire JmsTemplate bean failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jms, jmstemplate

I set up JMS application based on the http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-spring-jmstemplate-to-send-jms.html

However I cannot start tomcat because I've got following exeption:

```
    Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsSender': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate pl.zleek.test.jms.JmsSender.jmsTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My JmsSender class:

```
package pl.zleek.test.jms;

@Component
public class JmsSender {

@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

public void sendMessage(final String msg) throws JMSException {
    jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

}

My bean configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="pl.zleek.test" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="amqConnectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
      p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

<!-- A cached connection to wrap the ActiveMQ connection -->

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
      p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="amqConnectionFactory"
      p:sessionCacheSize="10" />



<!-- A destination in ActiveMQ -->
<bean id="destination"
      class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="FOO.TEST" />
</bean>



<!-- A JmsTemplate instance that uses the cached connection and destination -->

<bean id="jmsTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="cachedConnectionFactory"
      p:defaultDestination-ref="destination" />

<!-- JMS Consumer Configuration -->
<bean id="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
      p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="amqConnectionFactory"
      p:sessionCacheSize="10" />

<jms:listener-container container-type="default"
                        connection-factory="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory"
                        acknowledge="auto">
    <jms:listener destination="pl.zleek.test.jms" ref="listener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

My other spring configuration is in webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="pl.zleek.test" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

How can I solve this issue? IntelliJ Idea recognize bean jmsTemplate and could easily navigate between class and bean definition.

Comment: Is there any other Spring configuration file that you are using, if not is JmsSender part of the `pl.zleek.test` package?

Comment: I updated JmsSender source code with package. I also placed the other config file of Spring

Comment: You have a lot of duplicate configuration, it will be better to move all the UI specific configuration to `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file and the service specific things to the other controller file. Now be careful about the base-package that you provide, make sure the package names in both config files don't collide

Comment: I fixed code above. I pasted it accidentially incorrect. UI config is only in `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`. @BijuKunjummen what do you mean by base-package carefull treatment ? Base-package is the same in both config, however I tried to set `pl.zleek.test.jms` in Beans.xml - without effect

Comment: Thing is Spring creates components based on `basePackage` entry in component-scan, so now you have the exact same basePackage in two locations, so it is going to create the same component `jmsSender` twice, I am guessing one of them is not cleanly getting autowired..so you should take out one of them, keep the one with the jmsTemplate and remove the other. But then you probably have your controller also scanned right - if that is the case, it may be better to put a different basePackage for servlet config - say `pl.zleek.test.controller`

Comment: @BijuKunjummen - your last comment was a good point. I set base-package  to `pl.zleek.test.controller` in `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and `pl.zleek.test.jms` in `Beans.xml` where jms beans are defined. Now my tomcat starts without any errors. However there is still issue, because I got NullPointerException when I try to send a message - jmsTemplate is not initialized.

Comment: if it is easier, can you please put your code in github, I can send you a pull request with the fix. It is difficult to see what else could be off.